# Cadastrar somente alguns dados de um formulário C# Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um formulário de cadastro de pessoas, onde também já cadastro o endereço dela, aí surgiu a necessidade de poder cadastrar mais de um endereço para a mesma pessoa na hora em que estou cadastrando ela, mas eu não posso ter um formulário aninhado dentro de outro que pegue somente os dados de endereço, então, qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Quero ter um botão, que pega somente os dados que foram digitados nos campos referentes a endereço e cadastrar no banco, posso fazer isso com um JQuery que mandaria os dados pra minha controller de pessoas? Não quero fazer algo do tipo pop-up que aparece para cadastrar o endereço, e também não quero que redirecione para outra view, queria aproveitar a mesma view de cadastro de pessoas. 
Estou usando partial views, e usando viewModels diferentes.

Comment: Não sei se a pergunta está muito clara, mas você pode usar Jquery para ir carregando views parciais adicionais conforme o usuário quiser cadastrar mais endereços, e postar isso como uma coleção no `model`.

Comment: você quer ter um botão que faça o envio dos valores dos campos relacionados endereço para a controller e salvar no banco ?

Comment: Cara, pelo que eu entendi, o formulário é um só mesmo, não precisa de outro. Você deve ter um botão que faça a persistência do endereço no banco, passando como FK o ID do cliente. Ao persistir, ele grava e limpa o formulário. Esse envio eu faria por jquery, para a controller e lá chamaria a model que faria a persistência.

Comment: @RSinohara eu posso fazer com que o jquery adicione outra partial view de endereço, e então terei duas coleções de endereço sendo enviadas pra controller?

Comment: @ThiagoFalcão eu quero saber se essa é uma "boa" forma de fazer...

Comment: @pnet sim, mas esse botão, precisa enviar somente os dados de endereço, e não todo o formulário, e ele não pode limpar o formulário, pois a pessoa precisa continuar com o cadastro da pessoa, o endereço é somente uma parte...

Comment: Isso, um tipo assim: No jquery/ajax você enviaria isso. Vou responder como seria feito.

Comment: O cadastro da pessoa está sendo realizado... portanto, se entendi bem, o model precisaria conter uma coleção de endereços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulários aninhados não, mas você pode ter uma *View* que expande o formulário conforme sua necessidade de endereços.

Isto pode ser feito através do pacote [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/).

[Já escrevi várias respostas a respeito do uso deste pacote](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem). Se sua dúvida for mais específica, pode fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: Tenho duvidas sobre como usar o BeginCollectionItem, pelo que eu entendi, ele cria uma coleção do objeto que eu quero inserir várias vezes, como se fosse uma especie de vetor? e ai eu preciso ter um botão que vai fazendo isso?

Comment: @Aesir Isso mesmo. Normalmente a criação de um novo elemento da lista (não vetor) é feita da *View* para o *Controller* através de uma requisição Ajax.

Comment: Quando eu coloco a viewModel de endereço como IList: IList<EnderecoViewModel> na minha viewModel de pessoa, eu não consigo mais chamar as propriedades dela na partial view.

Comment: Então. Não mande `EnderecoViewModel` pra *View*. Mande outra *ViewModel* que tenha uma `IList<EnderecoViewModel>` dentro dela. Entendeu?

Comment: Acho que é isso que eu estava fazendo, coloquei `IList<EnderecoViewModel>` dentro de `pessoaViewModel` ai eu chamo a propriedade na view assim: `model.enderecoViewModel.propriedade` mas ai ele diz "Cannot resolve symbol propriedade".

Comment: Correto. Isto porque `IList` não possui um campo chamado `propriedade`. Se você quer `propriedade` de um `EnderecoViewModel`, precisa iterar `EnderecoViewModel` usando algo como um `foreach`, por exemplo.

Comment: Olhando seus exemplos, nas outras respostas, tem um `if` antes do `foreach` que verifica se a viewModel é nula, para então fazer o `foreach`, mas a minha ta vindo sempre nula, aí ele não renderiza a view.

Comment: @Aesir Agora é o caso de você abrir uma nova pergunta colocando este código pra gente analisar.

Answer (score 0):

No jquery/ajax teria isso:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Endereco/GravaEndereco',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ _logradouro: $('#txtLogradouro').val(),
        _bairro: $('#txtBairro').val(),}),
        success: function (data) {

            alert('Registro gravado com sucesso!');

            window.location.href = '/Endereco/Endereco';
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    })
```

Isso estaria no seu jquery. Dessa forma você envia os dados que estão nos campos do seu formulário. Na controller, então você teria seu método de persistir.

```
[HttpPost]
        public void GravaResponsavel(string _Logradouro, string _bairro)
        { 
            using(MeuEntities db = new MeuEntities())
            {    
                try
                {
                    resp.NM_Logradouro = _Logradouro;
                    resp.NM_Bairro = _bairro;

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {}
            }
        }
```

Seria mais ou menos isso. Adapte e veja se funciona.

Comment: O AP disse que queria cadastrar vários endereços durante o cadastro da pessoas... essa solução envia vários endereços, mas para associar ao usuário seria mais complicado.

Comment: Ele pode passar o ID do usuário como chave e lá no método, gravar o endereço pelo ID do usuário passado. Não vejo problemas nisso. Quando usava Delphi, chamávamos isso de Master/Detail.

Comment: Certo... o problema é que como a view cadastra o usuário, não existe ID ainda.

Comment: @RSinohara, depende de como fazer. Eu posso muito bem pegar o ID no momento do cadastro, pois ele quer cadastrar mais de um endereço, num único formulário. Então, deverá ser uma operação em cascata, primeiro um e depois os demais. No momento do BD gerar o ID do usuário, eu pego esse ID e trabalho com ele.