# Formulário usando BeginCollectionItem recebe viewModel nula no foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Quero fazer um formulário em que eu possa cadastrar vários endereços e telefones para uma unica pessoa, e quero poder fazer isso quando estou cadastrando a pessoa.

[Baseado nas respostas da minha outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80152/cadastrar-somente-alguns-dados-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio-c-asp-net-mvc-5), cheguei a parte em que coloquei a `telefoneViewModel` dentro de `pessoaViewModel` como uma `IList`, aí faço um `foreach` na minha *view*, que chama a *partial view* de telefone. Tenho um `if` que verifica se a *viewModel* é nula antes de fazer o `foreach`, mas aí minha *viewModel* sempre está vindo nula, e não renderiza a *partial view* de telefone.

Minha *controller*:

```
 // GET: Pessoas/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
     {       
           // salvando os dados     

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Minha view principal:

```
@model meuprojeto.ViewModels.PessoaViewModel

// resto da view...

<div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">
     @if (Model != null && Model.PessoaTelefoneViewModel != null)
     {
        foreach (var telefone in Model.PessoaTelefoneViewModel)
        {
           Html.RenderPartial("_Telefone",telefone);

        }
      }

</div>

//resto da view...
```

Na minha *partial view* tenho duvidas qual model chamar:

- `pessoaViewModel` e depois acessar as propriedades chamando: `model.pessoaTelefoneViewModel.propriedade`

ou

- `pessoaTelefoneViewModel` diretamente, mas acredito que depois a *controller* não vá receber ela, pois lá estou recebendo somente `pessoaViewModel`

ou

- não chamar nenhuma *viewModel* por que quando faço o `Html.renderPartial`, eu já não estaria passando a *model* pelo `foreach`?

*Partial view*:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Telefones"))
{
     <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, new {@class = "col-md-12 "})

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control "}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>

   //outros campos...
}
```

Se eu deixar sem o if, ele dá um erro de `System.NullReferenceException`. Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Antes de chamar a view a lista de ViewModels está nula? Talvez você tenha que criar essa lista antes de mandar pra tela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código está perfeito. Isso mesmo que é pra fazer. Agora você montar a *ViewModel* pra que todo este código faça sentido. Ou seja:

```
// GET: Pessoas/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var pessoaViewModel = new PessoaViewModel {
        // Aqui você poderia preencher os dados da pessoa. 
        // Minha dica é inserir uma lista com um elemento vazio em telefone.
        Telefones = new List<PessoaTelefoneViewModel> 
        {
            new PessoaTelefoneViewModel()
        }
    };

    return View(pessoaViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
 {       
       // salvando os dados     

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Outra coisa: procure manter o padrão. Se você usou "Telefones" aqui:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Telefones"))
```

A propriedade também precisa chamar `Telefones` na *ViewModel*:

```
public class PessoaViewModel
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<PessoaTelefoneViewModel> Telefones { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: E qual model eu uso na partial view de telefones? se eu usar a de telefones direto e não de pessoa, ela não é recebida na controller, e se eu usar a de pessoa, eu não consigo acessar as propriedades de telefone...

Comment: Na *Partial* você usa `@model SeuProjeto.ViewModels.PessoaTelefoneViewModel>`. Experimente preencher um telefone e faça um *Debug* na *Action* `Create` que recebe o `POST`. Tem que aparecer lá sim.

Comment: Aparece, mas como null, ai se eu colocar que a controller tbm recebe telefoneViewModel os valores são recebidos, eu poderia deixar funcionando assim, mas ai como ela receberia vários telefoneViewModels?

Comment: Como assim, receber vários `PessoaTelefoneViewModel`? Tá errado. Tem que receber só `PessoaViewModel` e os telefones estão dentro de `PessoaViewModel` como uma lista, como você mesmo colocou na pergunta.

Comment: Sim entendi isso, eu expressei errado, é isso que eu queria dizer, ela vai receber uma lista... mas ela ta recebendo null

Comment: Isso já é esquisito. Você tem como hospedar esse projeto em algum controle de versão e passar o link, tipo um Github?

Comment: Consegui resolver, tinha uma letra diferente no nome da collection e da propriedade, agora funcionou beleza, e agora o botão pra adicionar?

Comment: @Aesir Melhor colocar outra pergunta. Entra em Ajax e mais umas coisas.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80887/fazer-um-bot%C3%A3o-para-adicionar-propriedades-numa-lista-usando-o-begincollectionit