# Fazer um botão para adicionar propriedades numa lista usando o BeginCollectionItem C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tenho um cadastro de pessoas e preciso criar um botão para adicionar vários telefones e enviar para minha controller, estou usando o BeginCollectionItem, baseado na minha outra pergunta [Formulário usando BeginCollectionItem recebe viewModel nula no foreach](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80632/formul%C3%A1rio-usando-begincollectionitem-recebe-viewmodel-nula-no-foreach)  só falta a parte do botão, como faço?

Minha controller:

```
    // GET: Pessoas/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var pessoaViewModel = new PessoaViewModel
        {
            PessoaTelefoneViewModel = new List<PessoaTelefoneViewModel> 
            {
                new PessoaTelefoneViewModel()
            }
        };

        return View(pessoaViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
     {

            //salvando os dados         
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Minha view:

```
@model meuprojeto.ViewModels.PessoaViewModel

// resto da view...

<div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">
     @if (Model != null && Model.PessoaTelefoneViewModel != null)
     {
         foreach (var telefone in Model.PessoaTelefoneViewModel)
         {
            Html.RenderPartial("_Telefone",telefone);

         }
      }

 </div>
```

Minha partial view de telefone:

```
@model meuprojeto.ViewModels.PessoaTelefoneViewModel

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("PessoaTelefoneViewModel"))
 {
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, new {@class = "col-md-12   "})

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control "}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

   //outros campos...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere a *View* principal para o seguinte:

```
@model meuprojeto.ViewModels.PessoaViewModel

// resto da view...

    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">
         @if (Model != null && Model.PessoaTelefoneViewModel != null)
         {
             foreach (var telefone in Model.PessoaTelefoneViewModel)
             {
                Html.RenderPartial("_Telefone",telefone);

             }
          }

     </div>
     <p><a id="add-another" class="small-button">Adicionar Telefone</a></p>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#add-another").click(function () {
            $.get('/Pessoas/LinhaTelefone', function (template) {
                $("#tab-3").append(template);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

*Controller*:

```
// GET: Pessoas/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var pessoaViewModel = new PessoaViewModel
    {
        PessoaTelefoneViewModel = new List<PessoaTelefoneViewModel> 
        {
            new PessoaTelefoneViewModel()
        }
    };

    return View(pessoaViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
{

        //salvando os dados         
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult LinhaTelefone()
{
    var telefone = new PessoaTelefoneViewModel();
    return PartialView("_MinhaPartial", telefone);
}
```

## Funcionamento

- Ao clicar em "Adicionar Telefone", o *Controller* será acionado para formatar o pedaço da *View* que será incorporado ao código;
- O *Controller*, por sua vez, devolverá uma *partial* para o Ajax chamador;
- Feito isso, o JavaScript altera o `<form>` com o novo pedaço vindo do *Controller*.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! muito obrigado, me ajudou muito!!

Comment: Quando eu envio o formulário e o modelState não é valido, ele retorna pra mesma view de create, então o que eu digitei em telefone, é perdido... tem alguma forma de recuperar o que eu digitei antes?

Comment: @Aesir Sim, reenvie o *ViewModel* pra *View* logo depois do `if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }`. Assim: `return View(viewModel);`.

Comment: Nossa, como eu não tentei isso, Obrigado novamente.