# Adicionando text Box e gravando no banco. (com C#, entityframework 6.1.3)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Estou fazendo um projeto no Visual Studio 2013, com o EntityFramework versão 6.1.3, MVC 4.5.0.0 e utilizando *ViewModel*.

Estou programando uma página que se chama condição de pagamento. A página de criação terá um campo texto `nome`, 2 `radiobuttons`: "a vista" e "a prazo". Se o usuário selecionar a vista nada acontecerá.

Agora, se o `radiobutton` "a prazo" for selecionado, aparecerá um botão para adicionar `textbox`es dos dias a prazo para serem preenchidos. Eu preciso fazer essa programação de adicionar os `textbox`es conforme clique do botão de adicionar dias e fazer depois uma função para gravar no banco.

Acho que a função do botão de adicionar dias posso fazer em Jquery, e depois no botão de criação que adicionará no banco uma função na *Controller*.

Eu sei jquery, fazer adicionar as caixa de textos, agora estou um pouco perdido na parte do c#, a gravação no banco feita na *Controller*.

[image: Exemplo]

o codigo abaixo é da minha viewmodel:

```
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Id")]
    public int CondicaoPagamentoId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationsResources))]
    [MinLength(DataConfig.DATABASE_MIN_LENGTH_DEFAULT, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MinLengthAttribute_ValidationError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationsResources))]
    [MaxLength(DataConfig.DATABASE_MAX_LENGTH_DEFAULT, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLengthAttribute_ValidationError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationsResources))]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationsResources))]
    [MinLength(DataConfig.DATABASE_MIN_LENGTH_DEFAULT, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MinLengthAttribute_ValidationError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationsResources))]
    [MaxLength(DataConfig.DATABASE_MAX_LENGTH_DEFAULT, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLengthAttribute_ValidationError", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationsResources))]
    [DisplayName("Tipo")]
    public bool Tipo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationsResources))]
    [DisplayName("Dias")]
    public int CondicaoPagamentoDiasId { get; set; }
    public virtual CondicaoPagamentoDiasViewModel CondicaoPagamentoDias { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<CondicaoPagamentoDiasViewModel> CondicaoPagamentoDiass { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Cadastrado por")]
    public int UsuarioCadastroId { get; set; }
    public virtual UsuarioViewModel UsuarioCadastro { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data de Cadastro")]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
```

a adição é feita por:

```
this.add(objeto)
```

Comment: O caminho é usando o pacote NuGet chamado [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). [Aqui no site temos essas perguntas e respostas sobre este pacote](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=begincollectionitem). Se puder, edite sua pergunta colocando código como, por exemplo, da sua *View*, do seu *ViewModel*, etc., pra que eu possa dar uma orientação mais objetiva.

Comment: não entendi em qual parte está "perdido", você já tem alguma requisição, método ou algo do tipo pra salvar os dados ?

Comment: Thiago eu salvo o objeto: this.add(objeto), normalmente. Mas nesse caso especifico da minha pergunta eu tenho duas tabelas (condicaopagamento para guardar o nome e o tipo (prazo ou vista) e uma outra para guardar os dias (30,90,...) condicaopagamentodias).

Comment: Eu não sei como vou fazer a adição dos dias, já que será uma coisa dinâmica. E não somente um objeto.

Comment: Creio que [seja isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80907/20615) que você está procurando. Olhe o comentário do Cigano, que possui muitos outros exemplos. Caso nenhum deles lhe atenda, poste mais informações de como está seu `controller` e sua `view`, para ficar mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, já está tudo certo para você usar o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). Basta agora implementar. Minha sugestão para as prestações começa no código da *View* abaixo:

```
<div class="condicoes-pagamento" id="condicoes-pagamento">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var condicoesPgto in Model.CondicaoPagamentoDiass)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_CondicoesPagamentoDia", condicoesPgto);
        }
    }
</div>
```

A *Partial* `_CondicoesPagamentoDia` ficaria assim:

```
@model MeuProjeto.ViewModels.CondicaoPagamentoDiasViewModel

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("CondicaoPagamentoDiass"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CondicaoPagamentoDiaId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CondicaoPagamentoId)

        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">Dia:</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dia, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a class="btn red" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();">Excluir</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Repare que o código já pressupõe um botão de exclusão da linha em JavaScript. Há também um botão de adição que pode ser implementado da seguinte forma:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#adicionar-dia").click(function () {
                $.get('/SeuController/NovaLinhaDia', function (template) {
                    $("#condicoes-pagamento").append(template);
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Repare que este código faz uma chamada a um método do *Controller*. Não precisa ser assim. Eu uso desta forma para realizar validações do lado do servidor. O código ficaria assim:

```
    public ActionResult NovaLinhaDia()
    {
        return PartialView("_CondicoesPagamentoDia", new CondicaoPagamentoDiasViewModel());
    }
```

Fazendo o `POST` do formulário, você verá que `CondicaoPagamentoDiass` receberá todas as linhas preenchidas no formulário lá na *Action* do *Controller*.

Comment: Cigano no meu caso ele não está achando o BeginCollectionItem, preciso fazer algo na minha ViewModel?

Comment: Você instalou o BeginCollectionItem através do comando `Install-Package BeginCollectionItem`?

Comment: Instalei agora.

Comment: Agora é só seguir os passos. Qualquer dúvida pode me chamar aqui, ou abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: @section Scripts {
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ValidationMaskPartial"); coloco a partial nesse espaço? com aspas? Ou no helper?
       
       
       }

Comment: Não, a `@section Scripts` é apenas para os JS da *View*.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29367/discussion-between-jp-almeida-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você está com dúvida na recuperação os dados do formulário. Tente o código abaixo. Modelo:

```
  public ActionResult Gravar()
  {
    string[] chaves = Request.QueryString.AllKeys;
    Dictionary parametros = new Dictionary();
    foreach (string chave in chaves)
    {
      parametros[chave] = Request.QueryString[chave];
    }

    string nome = parametros["Nome"];
    string tipo = parametros["Tipo"];
    string dia2 = parametros["Dia1"];
    string dia1 = parametros["Dia2"];
    string diaN = parametros["DiaN"];

    // demais linhas de código.

    return View();
  }
```