# Usar ViewBag como contador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tem como eu usar o `ViewBag` como contador?

**O QUE PRECISO?**

Estou fazendo cadastros de telefones. Quando adicionar um telefone novo, mando minha `View` para o meu `Controller` e ele me retorna a `PartialView` dos meus `Inputs`.

Precisava de um contador, de quantas vezes eu adicionei o telefone, para referenciar os `Input`, por exemplo, adicionei um telefone:

```
<div class="telefone1"></div>
```

Adicionei outro

```
<div class="telefone2"></div>
```

aí que entra minha dificuldade, um contador em `MVC`

**CHAMADA AJAX**

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/AddTelefone',
    success: function (partialView) {
        $('#div').append(partialView);
    }
    });
```

**MEU CONTROLLER**

```
    //variavel global
    public int count = 0;

    public ActionResult AddTelefone()
    {
        ViewBag.count = count + 1;
        return PartialView("partialview");
    }
```

**MINHA VIEW**

```
@{
   var thing = ViewBag.count;
}
@Html.Raw(thing)
```

**ERRO!**

O meu `ViewBag.count` sempre está com o valor: `1`.

Comment: Já tentou criar uma variavel dentro do cshtml para receber o ViewBag e fazer o contador dessa variável?

Comment: Poste como você está chamando a partialView com os `inputs`. Creio que deve está utilizando ajax.

Comment: sim @Randrade na minha chamada `Ajax` eu mando ele pro `Controller` e ele retorna a `PartialView`

Comment: Adicione seu código ajax também

Comment: pronto @Randrade alterei a pergunta com o código `Ajax`

Comment: Esse contador você necessita para que? Irá enviar ele para algum `controller` no final?

Comment: nao @Randrade apenas integração com `jQuery` , por exemplo, excluir tal elemento de uma `div`, varios `id`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32673/discussion-between-furlan-and-randrade).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você utilizar somente a `ViewBag` em sua action não irá ter o resultado esperado. O que aconselho é enviar a quantidade do contador por parâmetro via `Ajax`, e retornar o valor.

Sua Action ficaria assim:

```
public ActionResult AddTelefone(int contador)
    {
        ViewBag.count = contador + 1;
        return PartialView("partialview");
    }
```

Com isso, basta retornar o valor da `ViewBag.Count` em sua partial para realizar o que necessita.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade está é a maneira **bem** errada de realizar uma relação de cardinalidade 1 para N em uma *View*. A maneira correta não é você "contar" o número de telefones. A maneira correta é você gerar tantos elementos de telefone quanto quiser, e o *Model Binder* ter a capacidade de contar quantos elementos foram gerados.

Isto pode ser feito manualmente, mas a maneira correta de fazer é usando o pacote NuGet chamado [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). [Já respondemos exaustivamente sobre este pacote](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=begincollectionitem). Se precisar, expando o exemplo para cadastro de telefones, mas não acho que precisa. [Aqui ensino a lógica em JavaScript para criar blocos de telefones](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80887/fazer-um-bot%C3%A3o-para-adicionar-propriedades-numa-lista-usando-o-begincollectionit). [Aqui tem o exemplo completo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80632/formul%C3%A1rio-usando-begincollectionitem-recebe-viewmodel-nula-no-foreach).

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, mas não to fazendo para o Model Binder contar quantos foi gerado, apenas para eu especificar algumas integrações em minha View, obrigado desde já